# How to get facebook friend_list using Graph API in Social Framework?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios6

i am able to login in `Facebook` using my native application.i have used `Social Framework` and wanna get `facebook` friends location using `Graph Api`.
but i am not getting any solution what should i do in next step.
can anybody tell me what to do next ?? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can request facebook friends using:

```
[FBRequestConnection
     startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                       id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                       NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSString *urlString = [NSString
                                    stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,friends.fields(id,name,picture),picture&access_token=%@",
                                    [[FBSession.activeSession accessToken] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
             NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
             NSLog(@"%@",url);
             ASIFormDataRequest *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
             [request1 setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
             [request1 setTag:101];
             [request1 setDelegate:self];
             [request1 startAsynchronous];
         }
     }];
```

and you will get the responce in:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if (request.tag == 101){
        NSDictionary *response = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
    }
}
```